# What are the best practices around accessing RDD's in Spark SQL API?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When using pyspark's SQL API, I sometimes see people recommend accessing the underlying RDD to perform a transformation. What is Spark's intentional usage around this? They say the RDD API will be removed in Spark 3.0, so should all code being written today avoid using the underlying RDD's, as a matter of both form and future comparability?

Comment: I am wondering why RDD would be removed as it has a different purpose. Can you quote?

Answer (score 0):

Spark sql and data frame APIs are high level APIs and easy to use with catalyst optimizer I.e the code you will write in theses APIs will be automatically be optimised by its catalyst engine.

RDD is a low level api and can only be used where you need to handle completely unstructured raw data that can’t be handled by the high level APIs.

Even if you will write the code using data frame and sql it will automatically be converted into rdds by spark.

It is advisable to write using high level APIs as you can utilise spark catalyst optimizer. If you will write using rdd then it won’t be optimized and you need to optimize your code.

Though I am not sure whether rdd api will be removed in future but currently most of the work is going on for data frame and sql support